# Google Maps overlay PNG image Not Showing

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I can not seem to be able to get the png image to overlay on google maps. I have looked at the googlemaps api v3 links and I tried to take there code and get it to work but I have not been able to get either the image or the map to display when I run the html code on chrome. I am very new to java script and html coding but I do have experience in python. My code is below, its just an edited version of the google maps api example but I cant get it to work. Am I missing something with trying to run html or is it something wrong with my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>      
<head>       
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-    scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        html, body, #map-canvas {
             height: 100%;
             margin: 0px;
             padding: 0px
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>
    <script>


var overlay;

testOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

function initialize() {
 var mapOptions = {
zoom: 11,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.743388,-74.007592)
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeID.SATELLITE
  };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    var swBound = new google.maps.LatLng((40.73660837340877, -74.01852328);
    var neBound = new google.maps.LatLng(40.75214181, -73.99661518216243);
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(swBound, neBound);

    var srcImage = 'test.png';

    overlay = new testOverlay(bounds, srcImage, map);

}

function testOverlay(bounds, image, map){

    this.bounds_ = bounds;
    this.image_ = image;
    this.map_ = map;
    this.div_ = null;
    this.setMap(map);
    }

testOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function() {

      var div = document.createElement('div');
      div.style.borderStyle = 'none';
      div.style.borderWidth = '0px';
      div.style.position = 'absolute';
      var img = document.createElement('img');
      img.src = this.image_;
      img.style.width = '100%';
      img.style.height = '100%';
      img.style.opacity = '0.5';
      img.style.position = 'absolute';
      div.appendChild(img);
      this.div_ = div;
      var panes = this.getPanes();
      panes.overlayLayer.appendChild(div);
  };

testOverlay.prototype.draw = function() {
      var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();
      var sw = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getSouthWest());
      var ne =     overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getNorthEast());
      var div = this.div_;
      div.style.left = sw.x + 'px';
      div.style.top = ne.y + 'px';
      div.style.width = ne.x - sw.x) + 'px';
      div.style.height = (sw.y - ne.y) + 'px';
    };

testOverlay.prototype.updateBounds = function(bounds){
            this.bounds_ = bounds;
                    this.draw();
                        };

testOverlay.prototype.onRemove = function() {
    this.div_.parentNode.removeChild(this.div_);
    this.div_ = null;
 };



google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Have you tried to specify the full url for the image, instead of test.png, write http://www.yourwebsite.com/path_to_image/test.png

Comment: thank you I went back through and fixed all the syntax errors and it still isnt working.

Comment: also for the path of the image, it is on my local machine and not necessarily a url, do i just have to specify the whole path to the image? @brance

Comment: @RyanB see my answer. I missed an error.

Comment: Your code works with a .png image when all the syntax errors are fixed ([fiddle using a png from Google's example](http://jsfiddle.net/at846362/1/))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of syntax errors. Correct them and your map works...

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/x1y9ocg1/)

Missing comma after this line `center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.743388,-74.007592)`

Extra `(` in this line: `var swBound = new google.maps.LatLng((40.73660837340877, -74.01852328);`

Missing `(` in this line: `div.style.width = ne.x - sw.x) + 'px';`

`mapTypeID` should be `mapTypeId` in this line: `mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeID.SATELLITE`

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the image URL is correct.

Simple test to verify that it is correct is by copying the 'test.png' file into the same folder as the script (html file in this instance) you've shown above.

If that works move the image back to its original location and reference it from the root level like so:

```
var srcImage = '/css/images/test.png';
```

Regards,

Comment: specifying the path to the .png file doesnt seem to be working either @Palvinder

Comment: Remove 'mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeID.SATELLITE' from the options and place map.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID); after var map = new... and it works.  Let us know if it doesnt and I'll send you the working code.

Comment: Oups, obviously you should replace MapTypeId.HYBRID in my example to MapTypeId.SATELLITE :) sorry a copy and past error!

Comment: I got it working @Palvinder, thank you so much for all of your help!

Comment: No problem, glad to have helped!

Answer (score 0):

Working code:

```
<script>
    var overlay;
    testOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

    function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 11,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.743388, -74.007592),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
        var swBound = new google.maps.LatLng(40.73660837340877, -74.01852328);
        var neBound = new google.maps.LatLng(40.75214181, -73.99661518216243);
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(swBound, neBound);

        var srcImage = 'test.png';
        overlay = new testOverlay(bounds, srcImage, map);
    }

    function testOverlay(bounds, image, map) {
        this.bounds_ = bounds;
        this.image_ = image;
        this.map_ = map;
        this.div_ = null;
        this.setMap(map);
    }

    testOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function () {
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.style.borderStyle = 'none';
        div.style.borderWidth = '0px';
        div.style.position = 'absolute';

        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = this.image_;
        img.style.width = '100%';
        img.style.height = '100%';
        img.style.opacity = '0.5';
        img.style.position = 'absolute';
        div.appendChild(img);
        this.div_ = div;

        var panes = this.getPanes();
        panes.overlayLayer.appendChild(div);
    };

    testOverlay.prototype.draw = function () {
        var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();
        var sw = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getSouthWest());
        var ne = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getNorthEast());
        var div = this.div_;

        div.style.left = sw.x + 'px';
        div.style.top = ne.y + 'px';
        div.style.width = (ne.x - sw.x) + 'px';
        div.style.height = (sw.y - ne.y) + 'px';
    };

    testOverlay.prototype.updateBounds = function (bounds) {
        this.bounds_ = bounds;
        this.draw();
    };

    testOverlay.prototype.onRemove = function () {
        this.div_.parentNode.removeChild(this.div_);
        this.div_ = null;
    };

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```